# Problems with data type in Foreign Keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a database for computer parts inventory. Here is my `Merger` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Merger
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL  IDENTITY, 
    [EntryID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [PartID] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [ModelID] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [QuantityID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [LocationID] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [DescriptionID] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Merger] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]), 
    CONSTRAINT [EntryFK] FOREIGN KEY ([EntryID]) REFERENCES [Entry]([ID]), 
    CONSTRAINT [PartFK] FOREIGN KEY ([PartID]) REFERENCES [Part]([ID]), 
    CONSTRAINT [ModelFK] FOREIGN KEY ([ModelID]) REFERENCES [Model]([ID]), 
    CONSTRAINT [QuantityFK] FOREIGN KEY ([QuantityID]) REFERENCES [Quantity]([ID]), 
    CONSTRAINT [LocationFK] FOREIGN KEY ([LocationID]) REFERENCES [Location]([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [DescriptionFK] FOREIGN KEY ([DescriptionID]) REFERENCES [Description]([ID]),
)
```

For some reason, the ones bolded come back with error:

> SQL71515: The column '[dbo].[Part].[ID]' is not the same data type as the referencing column '[dbo].[Merger].[PartID]' in the foreign key.

This doesn't make sense to me because data types are the same, in both the `Merger` table and whichever table the data is being pulled from. If anyone has any idea how to fix this, please help!

I've already tried to delete all primary keys and save, then re-add them and try the foreign keys again, but no luck.

I've moved the OP's comment into the question:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Part 
( 
    [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
    [Part] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Part] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]) 
)
```

Comment: Where's your definition for the `Part` table, particularly the `[ID]` column?  The error message is saying that `[Part].[Id]` not a `VARCHAR(50)` like `[Merger].[PartID]` is.   The two data types have to match if you're foreign keying one to another.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].Part
(
 [ID] INT NOT NULL  IDENTITY, 
    [Part] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Part] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "SQL71515: The column '[dbo.[Part.[ID]' is not the same data type as
>   the referencing column '[dbo].[Merger].[PartID]' in the foreign key."

Not only same data type but also check if they have the same length and attributes.

Writing this from my experience so have a check.

Comment: They do have all of what you listed above, as the same. All I did change for attributes was make the Identity Specification "True"

Answer (score 2):

In the `Merger` table the `PartID` column is defined as `VARCHAR(50)`.

In the `Part` table the `ID` column is defined as `INT`.

`int` and `varchar` are different types, the error message says just that.

You should change the type of the `Merger.PartID` column to `int` to match the type of the `Part.ID` column.

Comment: Nice catch Vladimir